# mingw + gcc + gnu + -ggdb -g3 but debugging failed "no source info"

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, makefile

Under Windows with same i686-w64-mingw32-gcc I have two C++ projects. Both with "-ggdb -g3 -O0" - the smaller project I can debug in Eclipse but the larger one says "No source available". Both projects with " -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"

I am failing to figure out what breaks it :(

Smaller project happy gdb:
[image]

Larger prodject not happy gdb:
[image]

Good makefile:
https://github.com/rusefi/rusefi/blob/temp_branch/unit_tests/Makefile
https://github.com/rusefi/rusefi/blob/temp_branch/unit_tests/rules.mk

Bad makefile:
https://github.com/rusefi/rusefi/blob/temp_branch/win32_functional_tests/Makefile
https://github.com/rusefi/rusefi/blob/temp_branch/win32_functional_tests/rules.mk

Both projects show symbols with objdump.exe  --syms:

Good project symbols:
https://github.com/rusefi/rusefi/blob/temp_branch/unit_tests/symbols

Bad project symbols:
https://github.com/rusefi/rusefi/blob/temp_branch/win32_functional_tests/symbols

I would like to be able to debug both projects. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

Update: I've found a work-around:

i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (32bit embedded into Cygwin64) does not work with gdb from cygwin64

but if everything is base 32 bit cygwin things work as expected! Just to reiterate - one project works with 32 compiler from cygwin64 while another one does not, so something must be different - but since I have a workaround I am good.